# when iterating through python dictionary in flask app only returns one value

Tags: python, dictionary, web-applications, flask, iteration

i am making an app with python, and im trying to use the Flask framework to make the code into a web app. but one issue is when I run the app with the framework

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
hi = {'a':1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
for z, x in hi.iteritems():
    return z
    return x

if __name__ == "__main__":
app.run()
```

it produces the following:
[the localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEdop.png)

why does it only run through one line of the dictionary? is there a way to get it to run through the whole thing?
[EDIT]
also, if I wanted to check for a certain key, such as c, and assign the value associated, 3, to a variable, how should I edit the following code?

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def hello():
    hi = {'a':1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
    for z, x in hi.iteritems():
        if z == b:
            number = x
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: That's what return does; returns from the function. You can't carry on after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're returning on the first iteration, depending on the output you want you could do something like this:

```
def hello():
    hi = {'a':1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
    return '\n'.join('{}: {}'.format(z, x) for z, x in hi.iteritems())
```